# "Rest of us" phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning, comparison

I come across the phrase in a sentence while I was reading Swan's PEU, unit about usage of `as... as... ; as much/many as`. So, the sentence is:

> She speaks French as well as *the rest of us*.

Could you explain it in more simple words?

Comment: The example sentence says nothing about anyone being able to speak French well. The example sentence's use of "as well" is different from the meaning of "well" than many of the answerers have been assuming. Your example sentence is basically saying that her level of French speaking is the same as the rest of us at speaking French. That is: we all (including her) might be terrible at speaking French, or we all (including her) might be average at speaking French, or we all (including her) might be somewhat good at speaking French; or etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Your example sentence is in the form of a comparative construction. There is a group of people which includes the writer/speaker of that sentence. This group of people, not including the "She" of the example sentence, can speak French at level X; the "She" can speak French at level Y; level X == level Y; that is basically what the sentence means.

Comment: Aside: Be aware that, although your example sentence doesn't really say anything about how well anyone can speak French (they can speak it poorly, or well, or not at all, etc.), the somewhat similar sentence *"She speaks French as poorly as the rest of us"* strongly implies that all of us, including "She", speak French poorly. (Yes, this all seems confusing, I know.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I shall not touch the ambiguous phrase *'as well as'* which can mean several things such as 'in addition', 'fluently', 'too', 'to similar degree' etc. I'm addressing 'the rest of us' as your concern. Refer comments down to this answer ***if*** you want to learn more about the phrase and *possible* meaning of 'as well as'].

I think it is in the context where *she* is sitting among a group and this sentence is spoken by someone from the group.

This simply means that she speaks French well ***just like all of them***.

> She speaks French well 
>  
>   We speak French well.

The *rest* is used to *exclude* her but include *all* to compare!

I tried a little to make it clear. :)

[image]

We often use *rest of us* in that way. Another example from [Mashable](http://mashable.com/2014/11/01/tokyo-had-more-fun-on-halloween/) reads

> Tokyo had more fun on Halloween than ***the rest of us.***

Meaning Tokyo beats all of us in celebrating and having fun on Halloween!

Comment: It might be worth to note that "as well as the rest of us" could be used in the other meaning, and we usually decide which meaning is intended based on the context. For example, here is a sentence that "as well as" means "too": *Let her choose for herself as well as the rest of us.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. True and that's why, to clarify it further in *this context*, I tried with picture separating 'well' with inverted commas. :)

Comment: Close, but not quite right. The original sentence says nothing about anyone being able to speak French well. The original sentence's use of "as well" is different from the meaning of "well" that you're assuming.

Comment: @F.E. I assume *'well'* as fluent/good way of speaking. I wrote a sentence down there 'They all speak French well'. I put that into inverted commas just to make the OP understand that *...as well as...* here does not mean *..in addition/and..*

Comment: @MaulikV But in the caption below your picture, there are no inverted commas. Anyway, the inverted commas don't do anything good or useful here.

Comment: *This simply means that she speaks French well just like all of them.* <== That is not true. The OP's example says nothing at all about how well anyone can speak French.

Comment: @MaulikV For example, F.E. might speak French as well as me - but my French is *absolutely shockingly awful*!!!!! So F.E  might also be very bad at French. Or, for example,, if the rest of us speak *really, really bad French*, and so does Bob - but Bob isn't *worse* than us, then: [***Bob speaks French as well as the rest of us, but still very badly***]

Comment: @F.E. Why digress the topic? My innocuous attempt was to make the OP understand that 'she' was excluded and 'all' were included by telling the sentence in concern. Now what degree you speak French is secondary. The phrase in question was 'rest of us' and I tried my best to illustrate it through image.

Comment: @Araucaria I'd NEVER prefer that way. I make things simple and not complex. I'd then say, She speaks French ***as badly as*** the rest of us! :)

Comment: @MaulikV but the problem is that'll confuse students when they see it used in the other way! For example: A: *Bob speaks really poor French* B: *But he speaks French as well as you!* The learner's going to be a bit mislead if he thinks that B is saying that both Bob and A speak good French! I like the helpful graphic though :)

Comment: @Araucaria to confuse the learner, you *need* to include ambiguity! Ask any Tom, Dick or Harry, *You speak French as well as me* -will mean you speak French well provided you are **not** fond of using sarcastic remarks! :) And again, the OP is concerned about 'rest of us' as stated in title and is further obvious in his question.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your question arises from a mistaken assumption about the words 'as well as'.  Often these words mean 'in addition to'.  As example is "She speaks French as well as German".

This reading of 'as well as ...' makes '... the rest of us' sound very odd indeed!

It helps to realize that your sentence uses 'as well as' in a quite different way.  The sentence could be written as follows:

> She speaks French as *fluently* as the rest of us.

Replacing **well** with **fluently** helps, I think, to make sense of the remainder of the sentence.

Comment: I first thought of the same. The adverb 'well' is in concern but I think OP is quite clear about it!

Answer (score 1):

The adverb "well" means "in a good, right or effective way". we can use well to make comparison between two people or things by putting "as" before and after well
such as "She can not sing as well as her sister"(Please look up the use of "as" in OXFORD DICTIONARY). The sentence in question has been used in this sense. "She speaks French as well as the rest of us". We speak French well. So does she.

An idiom formed from well is "as well as", which means "too or in addition to".
For example, we sell books as well as newspapers.  He plays cricket as well as baseball. The sentence in question has not been used in this sense.